# dynastyjs: how to find item(s) using secondary global index

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes, dynastyjs

I have a table: digital_asset, it's partition key is: id. It has a global secondary index: ean-index with partitioning-key: ean. I'd like to be able to query the table using the secondary index using dynastyjs. With aws-sdk I would do this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "digital_asset",
        IndexName: "ean-index",
        KeyConditionExpression: "ean = :ean",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":ean": ean
        },
        ProjectionExpression: "id, ean"
    };
    docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        else
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        if (!err) {
            resolve(data.Items.map(function(item){return item.id}));
        } else {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Using dynasty is much nicer, for example here's the query that searched by the primary index:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    return digital_asset.find(asset_id).then(function (item) {
        resolve(item.ean);
    });
});
```

This is what I tried, but got an error:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   return digital_asset.findAll({"ean-index":ean}).then(function (item) {
       resolve(item.id);
   }).catch(reject);
});
```

The error:

```
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.KeyConditions['id'].AttributeValueList[0].S to be a string
    at ParamValidator.fail (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
    at ParamValidator.validateType (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:218:10)
    at ParamValidator.validateString (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:150:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateScalar (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateList (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:103:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:90:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateMap (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validate (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:89:42)
    at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at callNextListener (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:75:9
    at finish (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:307:7)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:323:9
    at Credentials.get (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:126:7)
    at getAsyncCredentials (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:317:24)
    at Config.getCredentials (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:337:9)
    at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:70:26)
    at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:101:18)
    at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:661:14)
    at Request.transition (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at Request.runTo (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:394:15)
    at Request.send (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:358:10)
    at makeRequest (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:180:27)
    at svc.(anonymous function) [as query] (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:437:23)
    at tryCatcher (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at ret [as queryAsync] (eval at <anonymous> (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:163:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
    at Table.module.exports.queryByHashKey (node_modules/dynasty/lib/lib/aws-translators.js:142:31)
    at tryCatcher (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (node_modules/dynasty/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on using Global Secondary Indexes with Dynasty. Check out their source code (particularly [aws-translators.coffee v1.0 around line 135](https://github.com/victorquinn/dynasty/blob/1.0/src/lib/aws-translators.coffee#L135)). It looks like you might have to do something like `.query({ indexName: "ean-index" })` instead.